# Dynamically Adding context menu items to tableview columns

Tags: javafx, tableview, contextmenu

I have the following controller that is instantiated many times on my gui. The reason is beacause it has a tableview that gets filled with different kind of data. Looks like this

```
class Controller {
    @FXML
    TableView<Map<String, String> myTable;

    private Manager manager;

    //Each TableView has different ammount of columns with different names that get dynamically added to the table view using this function

    public void setUpColumns(List<TableColumn<Map<String, String>, String>> columns){
        myTable.getColumns().addAll(columns);
        addContextMenuToColumnHeaders();

    }

    private addContextMenuToColumnHeaders(){
        for (TableColumn<Map<String, String>, ?> tc : myTable.getColumns()){
            ContextMenu addToGraphContextMenu = createAddToGraphContextMenu(tc);
            tc.setContextMenu(addToGraphContextMenu);
        }
    }

    private ContextMenu createAddToGraphContextMenu(TableColumn<Map<String, String> String> tc){
        for (MangerHandledObject mHO : manager.getHandledObjects()){
            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(mHO.getName());
            menuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event){
                    //I want each menu item to have access to the column that is added to get the name of the column. Even after dynamically adding new menuItems
                    manager.callMethod(tc.getName());
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

The manager handled objects are not static. So the are added and deleted from the list that the manager keeps. I tried this

```
contextMenu.setOnShowing(......)
```

and before showing it will always check for the list from the manager and re-make the context menu items. But the problems is that when this executes I don't have access to the columns anymore. Is there any way to bypass this? Should I implement my own context menu to have a field of the column Name?

Answer (score 0):

It worked. But I had to add at least one dummy MenuItem on my context menu in order for it to appear.